# Is it less efficient to have more <?php tags?

Tags: php

I've always been one to write clean and readable code.  With that said, I've not been able to find out whether or not there's any difference in processing speed when using more or less `<?php` tags.  Here's some code for comparison:

**PREFERRED CODE:**

```
<?php while($condition): ?>
    <?php if($anotherCondition): ?>
        Hello world!
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**SHORTER CODE:**

```
<?php while($condition):
    if($anotherCondition): ?>
        Hello world!
    <?php endif;
endwhile; ?>
```

You see in the second code I use only two `<?php` tags, but I find the first code block much easier to follow.  Is there any loss in efficiency because I used more `<?php` tags?

Comment: It doesn't matter! Stick to writing readable code

Comment: Why do you prefer the code with more php tags?

Comment: Also, did you mean to have the `?>` on `line 2` of the second example?

Comment: ps - your while condition and if condition should be followed by a : colon, not a ; semi-colon

Comment: AlexLunix: Yes I did.
KaiQing: You're right, let me correct that.

Comment: If you're curious, you can do some benchmarking to try to figure out what the actual performance cost is (I'd suspect it's in the microseconds range).  Another thing to consider is that if you use a bytecode cacher, either style will compile to the same thing.

Comment: I'd say it does matter, that many php blocks is a pain in the ass to work with..

Comment: @cereallarceny If you have newlines like that outside of `<?php ?>` blocks those emissions will be sent to the client.  That can send HTTP headers automatically which prevents you from doing useful things like starting the session or redirecting.  Just keep that in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a performance implication but it is likely negligible.  Any space or tab that is not inside a `<?php ?>` block will be sent as part of the output of the PHP script.  To understand this consider this simple example:

The PHP code:

```
<?php while($condition): ?>
    <?php if($anotherCondition): ?>
        Hello world!
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Gets sent across the wire as

```
\n
\t\n
\t\tHello world!\n
\t\n
\n
```

While this PHP:

```
<?php while($condition):
    if($anotherCondition): ?>
        Hello world!
    <?php endif;
endwhile; ?>
```

Returns this:

```
\n
\t\tHello world!\n
\n
```

This is not the kind of thing you really want to worry about though, I say go for readable code.  I will say however that your first example involves a lot of extra typing, are you sure it's better?

Comment: Everyone is saying roughly the same answer Jason, but yours is worded the best: you get the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

No syntax issue can affect performance, so write readable code :)

Your second example is readable too, there is no reason to use 4 instead of 2 php blocks

Comment: It is readable.  However, I would argue that since I tab everything out evenly, it's easy to find code the first way when I'm quickly scanning a document.

Comment: Some of us like our code indented consistently.  In the version with fewer tags, the outer control block is indented farther than the inner block

Comment: Well, simply, using less or more php tags can't affect performance, so it's up to developer to decide, and this is very relative now.

Answer (score 3):

I tested your 2 kind of code + 1 *space-less* version to check the processing speed by introducing `$time_start = microtime(true);` before code and `echo $time = microtime(true) - $time_start;` after code.

Because the time to process is close to microsecond, the results may vary depending on many tiny factors. So I tested each code 10 times and I made an average time.

### Tests with printing text

**Prefered code**

```
<?php $time_start = microtime(true); ?>

<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php while($i <= 5000): ?>
<?php echo $i; ?>
<?php $i++; ?>
    <?php if($i == 5000): ?>
        This is the end! 
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php echo $time = microtime(true) - $time_start; ?>
```

Average time: 0.00366528034210207 second

**Shorter code**

```
<?php

    $time_start = microtime(true);

    $i = 0;
    while($i <= 5000):
        echo $i." ";
        $i++;
        if($i == 5000):
            echo "This is the end!";
        endif;
    endwhile;

    echo $time = microtime(true) - $time_start;

?>
```

Average time: 0.00243649482727052 second

**Space-less code**

```
<?php $time_start=microtime(true);$i=0;while($i<=5000):echo $i." ";$i++;if($i==5000):echo "This is the end!";endif;endwhile;echo$time=microtime(true)-$time_start;?>
```

Average time: 0.00242624282836913 second

### Tests without printing text

**Prefered code**

```
<?php $time_start = microtime(true); ?>

<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php while($i <= 5000): ?>
    <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php if($i == 5000): ?>
        <?php $a=$i; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php echo $time = microtime(true) - $time_start; ?>
```

Average time: 0.00143785476684571 second

**Shorter code**

```
<?php

    $time_start = microtime(true);

    $i = 0;
    while($i <= 5000):
        $i++;
        if($i == 5000):
            $a=$i;
        endif;
    endwhile;

    echo $time = microtime(true) - $time_start;

?>
```

Average time: 0.000472831726074218 second

**Space-less code**

```
<?php $time_start=microtime(true);$i=0;while($i<=5000):;$i++;if($i==5000):$a=$i;endif;endwhile;echo$time=microtime(true)-$time_start;?>
```

Average time: 0.000457286834716797 second

### Conclusion / Summary

**With printing text**
Preferred code: 0.00366528034210207 second
Shorter code: 0.00243649482727052 second *(33.5% faster than previous)*
Space-less code: 0.00242624282836913 second *(0.4% faster than previous)*

**Without printing text**
Preferred code: 0.00143785476684571 second
Shorter code: 0.000472831726074218 second *(66.1% faster than previous)*
Space-less code: 0.000457286834716797 second *(3.3% faster than previous)*

The average by 10 times is not really correct. It should be done by 100 or 1000 times with deleting extremes results to obtain a pretty good representation. But with this simple example we can see the significant difference between the 2 first codes, the 3th code is insignificant.

Comment: Wow Yann, great research!  I'd give you the correct answer had I not already given it to Jason (who did deserve it), but this is really interesting to note.  While the percentages are telling that there is a difference, when you're dealing with such a small amount of time I'm going to prefer readability over performance in this case.  Nonetheless, great work.

Comment: Thanks cereallarceny. Me too, I prefer to have a "clean" code. The differences are just in microseconds, so the small amount of time is really insignificant (except maybe for big company like Google, Facebook and others).

Comment: It is probably worth noting that this delay would be imposed mostly at compile or parse time.  In a compiled language the compiler would take the extra time to create an almost identical binary.  Clever interpreters will also frequently pre-read code and perform simple optimizations, in which case the penalty would be at start time only.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe its unreadable because of the indentation you are missing?
This is how I would do it.

```
<?php
  while($condition): //should be a colon not a semicolon
    if($anotherCondition): //should be a colon not a semicolon
?>
      Hello world!
<?php 
    endif;
  endwhile; 
?>
```